# PHP(Laravel): Converting Number

Tags: php, laravel, numbers, rounding

I need round a number from **1150 -> 1200 or 1110 -> 1200 or 1340 -> 1400** and So on
any Help! Ty! need fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with:

```
100*ceil($value/100)
```